# Excel formula - sumifs

Tags: excel-formula, sumifs

I have been digging into various websites but could not find out how to solve my formula.

```
=SUMIFS(Laundry!AH10:AH1006;Laundry!AE10:AE1006;"22 mar";Laundry!AG10:AG1006;"8")
```

I have a several tabs - each tab for a different day. In this case, my condition is "22 mar". When I copy my formula to a different tab - such as day "23 mar", I would like to have the condition changed accordingly - switch from "22 mar" into "23 mar" or whatever number it happens to be.

Basically I would like to copy the formula - and the condition would be changed according to what day I will input into a certain cell.

Do you have any idea, how to resolve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Assuming the "certain cell" is `A1`, change your formula to: `=SUMIFS(Laundry!AH10:AH1006;Laundry!AE10:AE1006;A1;Laundry!AG10:AG1006;"8")`

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! Works great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rather complex beast to get the tab name of the current worksheet:

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)
```

Applying this in your formula:

```
=SUMIFS(Laundry!AH10:AH1006;Laundry!AE10:AE1006; MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255);Laundry!AG10:AG1006;"8")
```